# Computing the gradient of $\det \left( \mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{X} \right)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I would like to compute the following derivative:

$$\frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}} |\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{X}|$$

Minka, in 'Old and New Matrix Algebra Useful for Statistics', says:

$$\frac{d}{d\mathbf{X}}|\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{X}| = 2 |\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}| (\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{T} $$

His reasoning is that because:

$$ d|\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}| = 2|\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}|\text{tr}( (\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{T} d\mathbf{X}  ) $$

We get the aforementioned derivative.

---

***Question:*** How do we get rid of the trace? What justifies this?

Is this saying that:

$$ \text{tr}( (\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{T} d\mathbf{X}  ) = (\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{T}d\mathbf{X} $$

That doesn't seem right to me.

@greg has some way to do with using the Frobenius inner product, but I haven't see that anywhere but on some answers.

Could anyone provide some insight into what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Given the derivative expression you've provided, the notation $|M| = \det(M)$.

Comment: We get rid of the trace because a directional derivative is one thing and a gradient is another. We extract the gradient from the Frobenius inner product.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo   We can do that? Man I am so lost haha I really need a reference to start learning this then instead of just jumping in and solving problems.

Comment: @the_src_dude Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3357120/339790). In matrix calculus, one uses the Frobenius inner product instead, but the idea is similar. Exploit the cyclical property of the trace till one obtains a Frobenius inner product in which one of the inputs is the direction matrix. The other input is then the gradient. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1933207/339790).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks! I am slowly getting the hang of this. Your references are of great help!

Comment: @the_src_dude Take a look at [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1797186/339790), too, as it's quite similar to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$Y=X^TX$$
Then the gradient of the function $(\log\det Y)$ is a well known result which can be looked up in the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) or on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula).
$$\eqalign{
f &= \log\det Y \\
G = \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y} &= (\det Y)\;Y^{-T} \\
}$$
All that's needed to answer this question is to perform a change of variables
from $Y\to X$.
$$\eqalign{
df &= G:dY \\
 &= G:(dX^TX + X^TdX) \\
 &= G:dX^TX + G:X^TdX \\
 &= G^T:X^TdX + G:X^TdX \\
 &= (G^T+G):X^TdX \\
 &= 2G:X^TdX \\
 &= 2XG:dX \\
 &= 2(\det Y)XY^{-T}:dX \\
 &= 2(\det X^TX)X(X^TX)^{-1}:dX \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}
 &= 2(\det X^TX)X(X^TX)^{-1} \\
}$$
where a colon is employed as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) \\
}$$