# Computing the matrix differential/derivative of the matrix$\rightarrow$scalar function $\log \det(BCB^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

I am trying to learn how to replicate the matrix calculus done in the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.11433.pdf.  To learn how to do this, I a using the following book I found (https://www.mobt3ath.com/uplode/book/book-33765.pdf), by Karim Abadir and Jan Magnus.

I attempted to start by find the differential of function H given below.  However, it does not look like I am on the right track.  Can someone tell me if my calculations below are correct so far?  Or at least if I am using the correct book to be able to understand the paper I listed?  I noticed that the book uses the 'vec' operator to treat the Hessian of a matrix function as a matrix while the paper uses an order 4 tensor, so I am not sure if I am using the right approach.  Thanks for the help.

My work so far:

Let $H(B)=\log\det BCB^T$ where $B$ and $C$ are square matrices of dimension $n$ and $C$ is symmetric.  Let $F(B)=BCB^T$ and $G(R)=\log\det R$ so that $H(B)=G(F(B))$.

\begin{align*}
      dF &= d(B)CB^T + BCd(B^T) \hspace{0.4cm} dG(R) = Tr[R^{-1} dR] \\
      \\
      dH &= Tr[(BCB^T)^{-1} (d(B)CB^T + BCd(B^T))] \textbf{ Take transpose}\\
      &= Tr[(BCd(B)^T+d(B)CB^T)(BCB^T)^{-1}] \\
      &=Tr[BCd(B)^T(BCB^T)^{-1}] + Tr[(d(B)CB^T(BCB^T)^{-1}] \\
      &=Tr[BCd(B)^T(B^T)^{-1}C^{-1}B^{-1}] + Tr[(d(B)CB^T(B^T)^{-1}C^{-1}B^{-1}] \textbf{ Use cyclic property}\\
      &= Tr[(B^T)^{-1} d(B)^T] + Tr[B^{-1} d(B)] = 2* Tr[B^{-1}d(B)] 
\end{align*}

The corresponding total derivative is then $DH=2*(vec (B^{-1}))^T$ by the book's notation.  Then I assume I would just 'unvectorize' this to get the derivative in the paper's notation?  Is this a good start to calculating the gradient of the loss function in the paper I listed.  Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1797186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, calculate the gradient for the full matrix.
$$\eqalign{
X &= BCB^T = X^T \\
\phi &= \log\det X \\
d\phi &= X^{-T}:dX \\
  &= X^{-1}:2\operatorname{sym}(dB\,CB^T) \\
  &= 2X^{-1}BC:dB \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial B}
  &= 2X^{-1}BC \\
}$$
Repeat the calculation for the diagonalized matrix.
$$\eqalign{
Y &= (I\odot X) = Y^T \\
\psi &= \log\det(Y) \\
d\psi &= 2Y^{-1}BC:dB \\
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial B} &= 2Y^{-1}BC \\
}$$
The Pham cost function is a linear combination of these functions.
$$\eqalign{
{\cal L} &= \frac{\psi - \phi}{2} \\
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial B} &= \Big(Y^{-1}-X^{-1}\Big)BC 
\;\doteq\; G_{std}
 \qquad&\big({\rm standard\;gradient}\big) \\\\
}$$
However, rather than the standard gradient, the linked paper utilizes the **relative** gradient, which is defined in terms of a *small* perturbation matrix $(E)$.
$$\eqalign{
d{\cal L} &= {\cal L}(B+EB) - {\cal L}(B) \\
 &= G_{std}:EB \\
 &= G_{std}B^T:E \\
 &= G:E \\
\\
G
 &= \Big(Y^{-1}-X^{-1}\Big)BCB^T \\
 &= \Big(Y^{-1}-X^{-1}\Big)X \\
 &= (Y^{-1}X-I) \\
}$$
This is the content of the first part of Eq (3) on the second page, except it
is written in component form, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
G_{ab} &= \frac{X_{ab}}{X_{aa}} - \delta_{ab} \\\\
}$$

---

**NB:**   The paper uses bra-ket notation for the Frobenius product, whereas I use a colon, e.g.
$$A:B = \langle A|B\rangle = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
because it's a lot easier to type (and it looks better).

The Kronecker-vec operation can flatten a matrix expression into a vector
$${\rm vec}(AXB)=(B^T\otimes A){\rm vec}(X) \;=\; Mx$$
Using the vec operation, 
a gradient matrix can be flattened to a long vector
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X}  &= G \quad&({\rm matrix}) \\
d\phi &= G:dX \\
  &= {\rm vec}(G)&:{\rm vec}(dX) \\
  &= g:dx \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}  &= g \quad&({\rm vector})  \\
\\
G,X &\in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n} \\
g,x &\in {\mathbb R}^{mn\times 1} \\
}$$
Similarly, a 4th order Hessian tensor 
can be flattened into a large matrix 
$$\eqalign{
{\cal H} &= \frac{\partial G}{\partial X}
  \in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n\times m\times n} \quad&({\rm tensor}) \\
H &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
  \in {\mathbb R}^{mn\times mn}  \quad&({\rm matrix}) \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.  I would like to now attempt computing the Hessian given in the paper.  However, I noticed the paper gives the Hessian as an order 4 tensor, but the book I mentioned above treats a matrix function Hessian as a bigger matrix.  Since you are familiar with matrix calculus, could you recommend a book to learn a more standard approach to matrix calculus, or at least tell me what to search to find one?  Your approach seems to have some noticeable differences from the book's formalism.

Comment: Also could you mention what your 'sym' operator means?

Comment: $${\rm sym}(X) = \frac{X+X^T}{2}$$

Comment: @xedg My approach corresponds to Chapter 13 of the book. In my experience, matrix calculus is best done using _differentials_.