# Why is the gradient of this determinant, $\det(I - AA^\dagger)$, off by factor of $2$?

Tags: derivatives, determinant, matrix-calculus, python, scalar-fields

I have banged my head on this for a couple of hours and I can't find what's wrong:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{pq}}\det(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger) &= \det(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger)\mathrm{tr}\left[(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger)^{-1}\frac{\partial(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger)}{\partial A_{pq}}\right]\\
&=\det(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger)\sum_{mnk}(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger)^{-1}_{mn}\frac{\partial(\mathbb{1}_{nm} - A_{nk}A^\dagger_{km})}{\partial A_{pq}}\\
&= \det(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger)\sum_{mnk}(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger)^{-1}_{mn}\delta_{np}\delta_{kq}(-A^\dagger_{km})\\
&=\det(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger)\sum_{m}(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger)^{-1}_{mp}(-A^\dagger_{qm})\\
&=-\det(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger)(\mathbb{1} - AA^\dagger)^{-T}A^*
\end{align}
$$

When I try it out numerically though, it's off by a factor 2:

```
def det(A):
    return np.linalg.det(np.identity(A.shape[0]) - A @ np.conj(A.T))

def ddet(A):
    return - det(A) * np.linalg.inv(np.identity(A.shape[0]) - A@np.conj(A.T)).T @ np.conj(A)

A1 = np.array([[0.1, 0.2],[0.2, 0.3]]) 
A2 = np.array([[0.1, 0.2],[0.2, 0.3+delta]]) 
delta = 1e-6

np.isclose((det(A2) - det(A1))/delta, 2*ddet(A1)[1,1])
>>> True
```

When the entries of $A$ are complex it's even more wrong, but let's solve the 2x issue first.

Comment: Are you sure you're not forgetting to multiply by 2 from differentiating the quadratic $A_{pq}^2$ for the chain rule?

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm computing $\frac{\partial}{\partial A}$ independently from $\frac{\partial}{\partial A^*}$ (as per Wirtinger calculus), so the expression in the determinant is linear in $A$.

Comment: Does $\dagger$ denote the Hermitian transpose? Is $\mathbb{1}$ the identity matrix or a matrix of $1$s?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1797287/339790)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For typing convenience define the variables
$$\eqalign{
P &= \Big(I-AA^H\Big) = P^H \quad\implies\quad P^T=P^*\\
\phi &= \det(P)\\
}$$
and denote the trace as a colon product
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
Then calculate the Wirtinger differential via [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= \phi\;P^{-T}:dP \\
  &= -\phi\;P^{-T}:\big(dA\,A^H+A\,dA^H\big) \\
  &= -\phi\;P^{-T}A^*:dA -\phi\;A^TP^{-T}:dA^H \\
  &= -\phi\;\big(P^{-1}A\big)^*:dA -\phi\;\big(P^{-1}A\big):dA^* \\\\
}$$
When $A$ is real, $\,A^*=A,\,$ $P^*=P\,$ and
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= -2\phi\;\big(P^{-1}A\big):dA \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial A} &= -2\phi\;P^{-1}A \\
}$$
In the general case
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial A} &= -\phi\;\big(P^{-1}A\big)^* \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial A^*} &= -\phi\;P^{-1}A \\\\
}$$
**NB:**   In order to test the complex case, your Python code should estimate the total differential instead of the gradient, i.e. by validating expressions such as the following
$$\eqalign{
A &= A_1 \quad\qquad&\implies\quad dA = A_2-A_1 \\
P &= I - AA^H \quad\qquad&\implies\quad dP = -dA\,A^H-A\,dA^H \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
\frac{-d\phi}{\phi}
=
\frac{\det(P)-\det(P+dP)}{\det(P)}
  \quad \overset{?}{=} \quad
{\rm Tr}\Big(\big(P^{-1}A\big)^HdA
 + 
\big(P^{-1}A\big)^T\,dA^*\Big) \\
}$$
If you insist on using the gradient, then you must use multivariate [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Functions_of_n_%3E_1_complex_variables) in order to code the correct expression.