# Gradient of a $\log\det$ function

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, logarithms, determinant

Given symmetric $d \times d$ matrices ${\bf G}, {\bf F}_1, \dots, {\bf F}_n$, let ${\bf F} : {\Bbb R}^n \to {\Bbb R}^{d \times d}$ be defined by

$$ {\bf F} ({\bf x}) :=  {\bf G} + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i {\bf F}_i $$

What is the gradient of the scalar field ${\bf x} \mapsto \log\det({\bf F}({\bf x}))$?

---

I tried to use the chain rule to find the gradient but I find the first part, derivative of $\log\det({\bf F}({\bf x}))$ is ${\bf F}({\bf x})^{-1}$ which shape is $n^2$, but the second part, ${\bf F} ({\bf x})$ is a vector to matrix function where its derivative is shape $n \times n^2$ where the final derivative shape is $n \times n^2$ but the expected shape of gradient should be same shape with $x$, I was wondering which step goes wrong?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1953518/339790)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1797287/339790)

Comment: The linked posts will help you understand how to calculate the matrix-wise gradient of $\log\det X,\;$ after which the component-wise gradients of your function are easy to calculate
$$\large{
\frac{\partial\log\det F}{\partial x_k}
 \;=\; \operatorname{trace}\!\big(F_k\,F^{-1}\big) 
}$$

Comment: I have read the related question you post; I now understand how to compute it thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

The differential is the linear form on $R^I$ defined by $$(h_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto \sum_{i\in I}\mathrm{Trace}(F^{-1}(x)F_i)h_i$$

Comment: Is that the directional derivative in the direction of $h$?